Monto functions (multiply onto functions)
This is an improvement over Hereditary property of bionto (bi-onto) functions.

Let $\,\ X\,\ Y\ $ be topological spaces. Set $\ A\subseteq X\ $ is said to be clopen in $\ X\ $ iff both $\ A\ $ and $\ X\setminus A\ $ are open. Continuous function $\ f:X\to Y\ $ is said to be monto iff for every clopen finite partition $\ S\ $ of $\ X\ $ there exists $\ A\in S\ $ such that $\ f(A)=Y$.
Open problem: Let continuous  $\ f:X\to Y\ $ be monto. Let $\ S\ $ be a clopen finite partition of $\ X.\ $ Does there exist $\ A\in S\ $ such that $\ f|A\ $ is monto?


Note: earlier, I had a nasty typo (now, it's fixed) -- sorry.

Yes.
Suppose not, then for each $A\in S$ there exists a clopen finite partition $T_A$ of $A$ such that there does not exist $B\in T_A$ such that $f(A)=Y$. Then $\bigcup_{A \in S} T_A$ is a clopen finite partition of $X$ no member of which surjects onto $Y$, showing that $f$ is not monto.

very good! Thank you! ####### The combination of bionto and monto turns out to be logically interesting.
